# How to update uploaded image using codeigniter. Must be from database as well as from the directory

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I have gone through many posts uploaded. I became able to update image link from the database and the new image which I selected get uploaded successfully but I am not being able to delete (unlink) the older image at the same time.
 
Here is my controller:

```
public function admin_profile_image()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('login_answer') != null){

        if('ADMIN'==$this->session->userdata('forredirect'))
        {
            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/uploads/profile_uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

           $this->upload->initialize($config);                              


            if($this->upload->do_upload('updateprofileimg'))
            {

                $image_data = $this->upload->data();                
                $profile_img = base_url("assets/uploads/profile_uploads/".$image_data['file_name']);

                $data = array(
                        'profile_photo'=>$profile_img                       
                        );

                    $this->load->model('update/updateAdmin');
                    if(!$this->updateAdmin->updateAdminImg($data))
                    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('profile_img_update_success','Profile photo updated successfully.');
                    redirect('update/admin_profile');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('profile_img_update_unsuccess','Profile photo could not updated. Please try again.');
                    redirect('update/admin_profile');
            }

        }

    }else{ 

return redirect('search'); 
}


}
```

Here is model:

```
public function updateAdminImg($data)
{
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('login_id',$this->session->userdata('login_id'));
    unlink($data);
    $this->db->update('admin',$data);
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('update/admin_profile_image');?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<label>Browse and Choose New Profile Image (Image size, Image dimension): 
</label>
<div class="form-group" style="line-height:33px;">
  <input type="file" name="updateprofileimg"  class="btn-primary btn-block">
</div>
  </div>
  <label class="col-lg-6 text-danger">
   <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; } ?>
  </label>
 </div>

   <?php echo form_submit(['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-primary','value'=>' Update']); ?>
  <?php echo form_reset(['type'=>'reset','class'=>'btn btn-warning','value'=>' Reset ']); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: You are trying to delete image after update

Comment: What should i do. actually i want to update the image already uploaded. but the older one should also be deleted simultaneously.

Comment: First, In the function where you are uploading the new photo. Delete the previous one the after that upload new

Comment: Please re-write my code and post me. I am so great full to you.

Comment: Try my answer. It will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller

```
public function admin_profile_image()
{
   $this->load->model('update/updateAdmin');
if($this->session->userdata('login_answer') != null){
    if('ADMIN'==$this->session->userdata('forredirect'))
    {
        //First, Get old image from database
        $old_image = $this->updateAdmin->get_old_image($this->session->userdata('login_id')); //Required parameter for image
        $image_with_path = 'file-path/'.$old_image;
        if(file_exists($image_with_path)){
            unlink($image_with_path);
        }    
        $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/profile_uploads'; //If your file uploading folder outside the application folder
        //$config['upload_path']          = APPPATH.'assets/uploads/profile_uploads'; //If your file uploading folder inside the application folder
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 100;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 768;

       $this->load->library('upload', $config);                              
        if($this->upload->do_upload('updateprofileimg'))
        {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();                
            $profile_img = base_url("assets/uploads/profile_uploads/".$image_data['file_name']);

            $data = array(
                    'profile_photo'=>$profile_img                       
                    );
                if(!$this->updateAdmin->updateAdminImg($data))
                {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('profile_img_update_success','Profile photo updated successfully.');
                redirect('update/admin_profile');
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('profile_img_update_unsuccess',$this->upload->display_errors());
                redirect('update/admin_profile');
        }

    }

}else{ 

return redirect('search'); 
}


}
```

Model

```
public function updateAdminImg($data)
{
  $this->db->set($data);
  $this->db->where('login_id',$this->session->userdata('login_id'));
  $this->db->update('admin');
}

public function get_old_image($login_id){
  return $this->db->get_where('admin', ['login_id' => $login_id])->row()->profile_photo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am going to try as you suggested.

Comment: Use $this->session->set_flashdata('profile_img_update_unsuccess',$this->upload->display_errors()); to see what is the actual issue in uploading

Comment: still struggling.

Comment: There were some error, but as i added $this->load->model('update/updateAdmin'); just before ($old_image = $this->updateAdmin->get_old_image($this->session->userdata('login_id')); //Required parameter for image) as you suggested in my controller its started working. But the problem is i am still stuck with the file-path. So I am mentioning here the complete directory structure. Starting with my project folder: pbulo->( a folder named assets)->( a new folder named uploads)->( a new folder again naming as profile_uploads)->(here is the image naming PIMG3.jpg). plz suggest file path.

Comment: If you are storing the image in the project folder but outside the application folder, Use FCPATH.'assets/uploads/profile_uoloads'. If you are storing images inside the application folder use APPPATH instead of FCPATH.

Comment: It is in the project folder but outside of application folder. i tried both two of your suggestions but still not working.

Comment: Send the screenshot of your project directory

Comment: And update your question what you have tried so far.

Comment: how send screen shot. I tried but could not able. please guide me. i am new user of stack overflow.

Comment: Right after your question ending, On the left side, there are three links. Use edit link and add photo

Comment: I don't know why but after clicking on edit link it takes me back to my question editor box where i try to add image and post it, but it displays msg - you are not allowed to add image.

Comment: it won't allow me until i earn 10 reputations.

Comment: By the way i try to explain my directory again. pbulo(It is my project folder) -> (within this folder there are 5 folders naming application, assets, system, tests, user_guide. out of these folders 'assets' is the folder created by me ) -> (within this folder i created a new folder named 'uploads')->(again in the 'uploads' folder i created a new folder named as 'profile_uploads')->(and finally all images are stored here).

Comment: FCPATH is your folder(pbulo). Then assets(FCPATH.'assets'). Then uploads(FCPATH.'assets/uploads'). Then profile_uploads(FCPATH.'assets/uploads/profile_uploads')

Comment: Yes Done. The mistake was as you had suggested to use (FCPATH.'assets/uploads/profile_uploads'). I was doing the same but there was missing a salash sign at end i.e, '/'. As I used (FCPATH.'assets/uploads/profile_uploads/') it started working.